# Jenkins: set admin access for a few individuals and "normal" access for all other users authenticated

Tags: jenkins

I would like for a few users in my team to get the full admin rights on Jenkins, but allow the rest of the company to have job creator rights. All users are added by Ldap. I've already added the role strategy plugin, and assigned my team members as under an administrator role. How do I add everyone else automatically to a job-creator role (with limited access)?

Comment: Everybody else is afaik anonymous. Change the permission there.

Comment: I want them authenticated (logged in through ldap).

Answer (score 4):

There is a hidden role called "authenticated" for all users who log in. I set that role to have limited permissions, all through the role strategy plugin. Odd that it doesn't mention this in the wiki page

Comment: You're right, this is the good solution, I missed this "authenticated" role.

Answer (score 1):

In the "Configure Global Security" section (Manage Jenkins), just add a the Anonymous user.

Next, configure the permissions for this user and it should solve your problem :)

All the people accessing your Jenkins server with no authentication should be able to create jobs.

Comment: I wanted people to authenticate. I figured it out though. There is a hidden role called "authenticated" for all users who log in. I set that role to have limited permissions, all through the role strategy plugin. Odd that it doesn't mention this in the wiki page.